# How can I implement a function depending on picked up items in C# and Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want a way to implement a certain function after collecting all the required items. The code is for picking up items like a screwdriver and cutter and depending on the number of picked-up items which is two I want to implement a function.

The screenshot below shows the picked-up items:

[image]

I tried to add a counter and then I increased the counter after the icon was enabled but it counts one time.

The code for picking up items is below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PicUpTools : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectWithPlayer,PicUpText;
    
    public RawImage objectRawImage;
    private int counter = 0;
    void Start()
    {
        objectWithPlayer.SetActive(false);
        objectRawImage.enabled = false;
        PicUpText.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            PicUpText.SetActive(true);
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
            {
                gameObject.SetActive(false);
                objectWithPlayer.SetActive(true);
                objectRawImage.enabled = true;
                counter++;
                PicUpText.SetActive(false);

                if (counter==2)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Elements have collected");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        PicUpText.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: u want a method that has a different behaviour depending on the number of items collected?

Comment: I for one have no idea what you mean by "implement a function depending on picked up items" - what is that function doing? Where is your own attempt?

Comment: @UnholySheep for example:  ` if (objectRawImage.enabled == true)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Elements have collected);
                }`

Comment: @Nefisto Exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line with the answer to the previous question. Here, it is better to consider a **`Dictionary`** to record the count of items. The `Dictionary<>` can record the number of items per key, so after each time the item is obtained, add one to its member number.

```cs
private Dictionary<string, int> itemDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) // First Check KEY cuz of optimization
    {
        if(other.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out Item item))
        {
            item.PickUp();
            if (itemDictionary.ContainsKey(item.type))
            {
                itemDictionary[item.type]++;
                Debug.Log($"{name} has {itemDictionary[item.type]} of {item.name}.");
            }
            else
            {
                itemDictionary.Add(item.type, 1);
            }
        }
        
        if (itemDictionary[item.type]==2)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Element: ({item.name}) have collected");
        }
    }
}
```

In order to determine which items belong to the same family, it is better to define the Type model as a String and then mark similar items with the same code.

```cs
public class Item : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string type = "Wrench"; // Assign Type String for items.
    
    public Image UI_Image;
    public void PickUp()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        UI_Image.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        //....
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I got the following error:  ``` ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].FindEntry (TKey key) (at <890d6fe26e8c408ea64b353e791fafce>:0)
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].get_Item (TKey key) (at <890d6fe26e8c408ea64b353e791fafce>:0)
PlayerScript.OnTriggerStay (UnityEngine.Collider other) (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerScript.cs:27)```

Comment: @saad Move the `if (itemDictionary[item]==2)` into the body of the `TryComponent` and the problem will be solved. (I edited the answer)

Comment: The error has gone, but this part was not executed. nothing was printed. It should print ELEMENTS HAVE COLLECTED

Comment: @saad I updated the answer. Because the instance of each item is different from the other. The dictionary considers each one as a separate item (so always count is `1`). to fix problem Change the key model to string and define the same type for similar items.

Comment: Thanks, it works now, just a small thing I don't know why it prints just the name of the cutter. I think it should print the name of the screwdriver and cutter.

Comment: @saad The Type name inside the code is set as default. Basically, you have to specify their types inside the inspector.

Comment: in the inspector the type = "Wrench", how can I assign text in unity. Sorry I didn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a public addObject function on the player script, and call it in the Pickup class when the object is picked up.

That addObject would increment an int counter in the player script, you could then check when it gets to two and call whatever function you want.

Comment: Do you mean on the player script, is on the player controller?

Comment: Yes that is probably correct if you can modify it, though you might want to make it separate scripts in the long run.